# using an iterator of a map<char,strring> to return a pointer map<char,strring>*

Tags: c++, c++11, pointers, data-structures

Im working on a university assignment hence the pedantic nature of my question.

The assignment is to implement a hash table, of size 26. The hash function is simply the last letter of the word {`hash(apple) = e, hash(car) = r`}. I have chosen to use a `map<char, string>` char for each letter of the alphabet (hash) and string to store the input words (key).

I want to search the map and return a pointer to the position where a new key needs to be added. The search aspect I have working its the pointer I am having trouble with. any assistance would be much appreciated.

```
map<char,string>* search(map<char,string>* hashTable, string key, char hashVal){

    map<char,string>::iterator it;
    for(it = hashTable->begin(); it != hashTable->end(); ++it){
        if(I want to return this address of hashTable){
            return &it->hashTable || something to that effect 
        }
    }
)
```

The reason I want to do this is to fulfil the following use case in an add() or remove().

```
void remove||add(map<char,string>* hashTable, string key){
    map<char, string>* temp = search(hashTable, key, hashVal);
    temp->second == NULL||key;
}
```

NOTE:
I understand that the map library has functions like at() and find() however using them wont prove my understanding hash tables. This is pedantic nature of university data structures assignments 2020 I was referring to.

ps. let me know if you think there is a better library to base my hash table off. linked lists maybe?

Comment: why not return the iterator? Also, shouldn't you need a multimap or a map to a collection of strings

Comment: Also, if you know the size beforehand then you could better just use a std::vector or even a std::array to make it have a lot less indirection

Comment: I'll look into using a vector, I'm more familiar with them. Initially I was trying to return the iterator but wouldn't seem to work and felt awkward,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I think you are attacking this the wrong way. `std::map` is already a fully fledged, hash-table-like container (cringe, yes I know it is not really, don't hurt me!). Using it will most likely lead you astray from what you should learn from this exercise.

`std::vector` is your friend.   If you have your ASCII table ready, you should be able to formulate a good hash function: `hash(val) -> Index`.

The example might strike you as pedantically defined, but it will make all the properties of hash tables strikingly obvious (like in your face kind of obvious).

Ah, and to answer your question: std::next has a good overload for getting a pointer/iterator to an element.

*edit* Addendum:

**(hint)** The killer feature of hash tables would probably get lost when using linked lists...

Comment: Funny story is `std::unordered_map` is actually implemented using a single linked list. In this case the hash table only contains pointers to the list nodes.